# Is it possible to override the values set by expand_limits() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following function:

```
plotSmth <- function(...) ggplot2::ggplot(...) + 
  expand_limits(x =c(0), y =0)
```

Is it possible to override the values set by the `expand_limits()` of the `plotSmth`

I tried something like:

```
plotSmth(thisIsData, aes(x=xhere, y=yhere, colour=as.factor(foo), lty=as.factor(bar)  )  ) +
  expand_limits(x=c(10), y=c(0, 25))
```

but it still did not override the `0` for the `x` axis set in the `plotSmth`'s `expand_limits()`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) with sample input data and clearly describe what the desired output is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expand_limits` adds a dummy layer with data to stretch the axes, so you cannot undo that easily. Three options come to mind:

1. don't use `expand_limits` in `plotSmth`, maybe `xlim()`/`ylim()` would do the job instead, and those can be reset;
2. force the limits with e.g. `coord_cartesian()`;
3. remove the dummy layer

.

```
p = qplot(1:2,1:2) + expand_limits(x=-1e3)
p
p$layers[2] <- NULL
p
```